# RegEX to search links in a text file?

Tags: regex, notepad++, sublimetext3

Im trying to clean a database that contains a lot of links that doesnt work

The problem is that there are a lot of links for picture and every picture has a different name of course.

Is it possible to select the entire link That contains "http://example.com/img/bloguploads/" with a regEX ?

Comment: Why do you need regex for this? Just use the normal find: CTRL+F

Comment: Regex to search text in Notepad++?

Comment: @ctwheels I needed to select the entire link, with CTRL+F you can't do that , ctrl+f would only select the "http://example.com/img/bloguploads/" part and not the actual name of the picture .

Comment: @Sunil Regular Expressions to search and select an entire link so that i can select all the links on a text file that contains "example.com/img/bloguploads/xxxx.jpg"" and replace them with #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can find all hyperlinks with:

```
http[s]?://.[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\-]+
```

And all `example.com` links with:

```
http://example\.com/img/bloguploads/\S+
```

Comment: Why are you escaping the slashes? And character in the character class? That's making the regex harder to read.

Comment: You don't need to put `s` in brackets (`[s]`). You also don't need to escape everything (as @Toto mentioned). You also should escape the `.` when it's not in a set: `https?://example\.com/img/bloguploads/\S+`. Also, you can easily shorten this to `\S+` since links may have parameters `variable=value` or fragments `#` in them.